# How are APIs made?

Tags: c++, api

Actually I was asking, how a library like SFML can be made from scratch using C++?

I've wrongly mistaken a **Library** for an **API**,

The question is, unintentionally, repeated by me and here's the link for it:

[How create a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741952/how-create-a-library)

Comment: An API is any interface that an automated system can use to interact with your system.  This is a *very* broad and open-ended concept.  Some APIs are web services, some are system calls, some are database writes, some are file writes, etc.  Anything you design which allows another application to interact with your application is an API.

Comment: This is a valid question - one may not understand the concept of API in C++, especially the pragmatics of it.

Comment: i'm afraid u didn't understand me. I've learnt the basics of c++ but it's limited to console and i want to expand my knowledge to GUI and gaming so i would use some API like SFML. I know it's written in c++. How can I, and i don't intend to do but just to understand, make a similar one using c++ i've learnt.

Comment: I mean how to access things like sound and graphic card to create a graphical interface? I didn't leant something like that in c++.

Comment: @OMarElgazzar And how is that related to creating an API? An API is a `P`rogramming `I`nterface of an `A`pplication. Did you mean how operating systems implement their APIs?

Comment: SFML is an API that's written in c++, My question is simply " How can I write a similar one?

Comment: Search you favorite C++ text book for the section on writing functions.  The function declaration is an API.  Simple.

Comment: Notice that sound, images, mice, keyboard are *not* standardized in C++11 .... So you need something more, e.g. a target-specific library or a cross-platform framework

Comment: @OmarElgazzar: what kind of API do you have in mind? What for? On which computer, which operating system?

Comment: So, how SFML library written in c++ while it provides an access to images, sounds, network ..etc

Comment: SFML is, like libsdl or Qt, a free software library. So you can just study their source code.

Comment: May I get your facebook name so that i contact with you?

Comment: Do you mean that the implementations of this API not written in c++ , but a more sophisticated language or what?!

Comment: It is written in C or C++, but it uses some operating-system specific API which is not standardized in C++11 (but elsewhere, e.g. POSIX or Linux)

Answer (score 4):

In practice, an [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) is simply the *documented* interface of some existing (reference or sample) implementation.

In theory, one could design an  API in the abstract. Practically doing that without any implementation is a costly mistake (because without implementation there are lot of details you won't think about).

Read also about [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Notice that pure standard [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) does not offer much about interacting with the outside world: the C++11 standard does not know about directories, keyboard, mices, screens, sounds, networks, GUIs etc. Your operating system probably have more relevant *additional specific* libraries. Learn more about [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) which could be understood as a [standardized API](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) for operating system services (sadly, some proprietary OSes sold by MicroSoft are *not natively* POSIX compliant; it is rumored that you might buy some POSIX-like interface to their Windows OS, which have their own [Windows API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API)).

If you want to implement something, you'll need to know well the target platform, i.e. the operating system that you want to support. For Linux, start reading [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html), [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [intro(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html), etc... and study in details the source code of [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) implementations (see e.g. [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) ...) relevant to your goal.

If you want to be cross-platform (e.g. be able to compile the same code on Linux and on MacOSX), better use & leverage on existing cross-platform frameworks like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/), or (if they are relevant for your needs) [libsdl](http://www.libsdl.org/) or [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php). These frameworks are using some operating system specific APIs (and try to define some common abstraction above them).

<sup>PS. In practice, designing a good API is a difficult art. Well documenting it is essential. If possible, make your implementation free software, and try to get advices and help about it.</sup>