# How create a library?

Tags: c++, sfml

**How can I make my own GUI library e.g. SFML?**

This question is for the purpose of understanding how GUI libraries work, not to actually make my own library.

I asked what I needed to do so. Can I open my editor and write some C++ code, importing some libraries and that's it. Or it's more complicated?

Comment: You need additional tools to combine all the `.o` files into `.a` or `.so` library files. But you don't have to do anything to the system unless you want the library to be available in the default library search path.

Comment: So how can i access hardware such as graphics card, sound without using system files?

Comment: You do that by accessing device files or making system calls. That's part of the operating system.

Comment: "Using a library" does not necessarily (or even *usually*) imply "not using system files". Libraries usually work on top of your current system, giving access to new functions or easier access to existing ones.

Comment: So, when i want to render a window, for example, i call some functions pre-established by the OS using some dll files. Am I right?

Comment: @Barmar how can i access certain device? i need code example please ..

Comment: Every device is different. You access the terminal with `/dev/tty`. You access network devices by using sockets.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, which is how to package the code into a library. Whether you do it in a library or in a standalone program, you access the device the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a shared and static library with the gnu compiler [gcc] : http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html

Answer (score 2):

A library is "just" a bunch of classes and functions, so you write it like a normal program. The only thing that is different is when you compile it: you have to create a static/dynamic library file.

Comment: maybe my question is not clear, but i meant how to create a library to access hardware like SFML.